# Parsing Wikipedia Math

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get plain text from Wikipedia, but I still get math/equations/latex.  Is there a way to exclude all of those with the URL? I looked around at all of the options and I can't find anything for it.  When I parse the Calculus page I get the equations going down the page with a bunch of \n and spaces...because it's text it goes through.  If there isn't any way to remove it using the URL, does anyone have a regex or function to remove these sections in JavaScript?

Using URL
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext&redirects=1&titles=Calculus

I get:

```
        d
        y


    {\\displaystyle dy}
   were taken to be infinitesimal, and the derivative 



        d
        y

          /
```

I built some basic Reg Expressions, but I can't guarantee that WIKIs format will stay standard across pages, and I might actually delete text content that I want:

```
.replace(/(\\n)\s{2,}/gm, "\n") .replace(/\n{2,}/gm, "\n\n").replace(/\n{.+}\n/gm, "\n\n").replace(/\n{2,}/gm, "\n\n")
```

Comment: You might find it easier to request the content with HTML tags, and to then just remove the `<math>` elements as a whole, rather than trying to pick apart plain text, and then just remove all remaining HTML tags afterwards.

Comment: Would there be a way in JS to get the text and the html then remove all the math from the html then..... somehow mesh the two?   Like a diff...to tell the text string what part to remove?  Removing HMTL with regex scares me a bit..

Comment: If I substring the htnl sections from math tags...then regex remove all html from the substrings then go against the text substrings where there are a lot of spaces and /n's.....hmm I don't think I have that right though...seems I could still mess up the text content.  Maybe to make regex safer for html tag removals... you split the text on html tags then remove all of them and join it all back together?  This seems to segregate tags into their own cells, so it doesn't delete text too.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&redirects=1&titles=Calculus) endpoint returns the text with HTML. You should be able to regex out the `<math>` and HTML elements. But have you considered the fact that the content isn't going to make sense if you remove the equations to which it refers?